# Strange Errors in Security and Compliance

Tags: security, exchange, microsoft-dfo365, compliance

I'm getting an odd error in many of my security and compliance pages, error is as follows or a varient of the same:

The requested search root 'APCPR06A002.prod.outlook.com/ConfigurationUnits/XXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/Configuration/Transport Settings/Rules/SafeLinksVersioned' is not within the scope of this operation. Cannot perform searches outside the scope 'apcprd06.prod.outlook.com/Configuration/Services/Microsoft Exchange/ExchangeLabs'.

any advice? :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error messages, you could modify the recipient scope, run the command:  Set-ManagementScope
For more details: [Set-ManagementScope](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/role-based-access-control/set-managementscope?view=exchange-ps)
[How to Modify Recipient Scope in the Exchange Management Shell](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/how-to-modify-recipient-scope-in-the-exchange-management-shell/)